# windows 8.1 windows key not working

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

Recently my computer updated itself.  I *think* one of these updates caused my windows key on my keyboard to stop functioning.  I tried both the left and right windows keys.  WINDOWS + R, WINDOWS key to bringup the tiles pane, WINDOWS + D...none of the shortcuts work.

This is a windows 8 machine (8.1 I think).  Googlin' didn't come up with much.  I have a G15 keyboard, however this problem appears to be somewhat common and not keyboard related.

Comment: What is your question? This sounds like a hardware failure. The simplest solution replace the hardware.[http://www.autohotkey.com/](http://www.autohotkey.com/) can get around this by creating a new shortcut that sends that existing shortcut.

Comment: @Ramhound - Please re-read the question.  As I pointed out I suspect this is not a hardware issue and may be related to windows update.  I also pointed out this is a common 8.1 issue seemingly unrelated to the keyboard hardware.  Its also very unlikely that both windows keys would fail at the same time.

Comment: I read the question.  Your description of the problem sounds like a hardware problem.  I would install the `G15` drivers again.

Comment: @Ramhound - Good suggestion.  I installed the latest G15 drivers from Logitech's support site.  Problem is still there.

Comment: What others say, and what you suspect are just guesses, you need to troubleshoot.  Try a different known-good keyboard, and/or try that keyboard on another computer to eliminate that it's hardware failure of the keyboard.  Software-wise: Does it work in Safe mode?  How about in a 3rd-party OS? As-is, I'm not sure what your question is asking, nor have you shared what you've tried already (aside from "Googlin'").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a joystick switch on the G15 keyboard which disables the windows key and menu keys so as not to impact gameplay with accidental keystrokes.  I had never used this feature.  Somehow I must have activated the switch.  I toggled the switch back and the keys work again.

Details:  http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9873/~/using-my-g15-joystick-switch

Comment: This was exactly the solution for me as I had this very problem today. Thank you Mr Mackey.

Comment: Cleaned my keyboard and was worried I broke it. Must have hit the switch while cleaning it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: VERY NICE! it so happens, as i was reading this i was like "i dont have this button...wait, i have a g15 too...so it MUST be here lol. Sure enough, there it is and its working lol. Thanks

Comment: I had a similar experience with an Acer keyboard with no obvious switches. It does have an *Fn* key which enables the secondary functions on many of the F keys such as snooze, search, email, browse, volume controls, and media player. Apparently the combination of *Fn+Windows* toggles whether the Windows key is recognized. Since the two keys are side by side, this is easy to do by accident. Now I'm curious what it turns the Windows key into, or if it just disables it completely.